# How to unpack the result when iterating through cell array?

Tags: matlab

I want to iterate through a cell array filled with strings and then use the strings in another function call. Like this:

```
flavorDb = containers.Map();
flavorDb('banana') = 'awful';
flavorDb('lemon') = 'sour';
flavorDb('orange') = 'delicious';

for fruit = {'banana' 'lemon' 'orange'}
    disp([fruit ' is ' flavorDb(fruit)]);
end
```

Questionable grammar in printout aside; the result of the lookup in `flavorDb` is the following:

```
Specified key type does not match the type expected for this container.
```

and this is because the variable `fruit` contains `{'banana'}` instead of `'banana'`. What is a better way to do this?

Comment: bonus fun fact: you could use `for fruit = flavorDb.keys` instead of defining the cell array manually

Comment: @Trogdor that doesn't really help him craft specific queries

Comment: however this helps me, as i wasnt aware how to get them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved in many ways. Depending on how further complexity is added to your code, any of these might be appropriate.

#### Use the `for` iterator on the cell array and unpack each result

```
disp([fruit{:} ' is ' flavorDb(fruit{:})]);
```

or

```
disp([fruit{1} ' is ' flavorDb(fruit{1})]);
```

#### Use a `for` iterator on an index array and index into the cell array

```
fruit = {'banana' 'lemon' 'orange'};
for iFruit = 1:numel(fruit)
    disp([fruit{iFruit} ' is ' flavorDb(fruit{iFruit})]);
end
```

#### Use `cellfun` to iterate over the array elements

```
cellfun(@(fruit) disp([fruit ' is ' flavorDb(fruit)]), {'banana' 'lemon' 'orange'});
```

#### Use the `values` method for `containers.Map` objects to map the values to an array the same shape as your input

```
fruit = {'banana' 'lemon' 'orange'};
output = [fruit; flavorDb.values(fruit)];
fprintf('%s is %s\n', output{:});
```

Comment: Whoa! Is this CAPS LOCK on speed?

Comment: Fair! I wanted clear subdivision between separate options and top-level headers seemed the most semantically attractive but clearly not the most aesthetically helpful. Now switched to third-level headers which is a less shouty compromise I think.

Comment: Or you can use "----" without the quotes between sections to sorta separate them out.

Answer (score 3):

Even though i find your dislike of bananas distrubing, i am willing to help you:

```
flavorDb = containers.Map();
flavorDb('banana') = 'awful';
flavorDb('lemon') = 'sour';
flavorDb('orange') = 'delicious';

for fruit = flavorDb.keys %instead of {'banana' 'lemon' 'orange'}
    disp([cell2mat(fruit) ' is ' flavorDb(cell2mat(fruit))]);
end
```

would be enough as you get the string out of the cell. alternatively you have to go for the whole cell construct

```
fruit = flavorDb.keys;

for i = 1:length(fruit)
    disp([fruit{i} ' is ' flavorDb(fruit{i})]);
end
```

Comment: Thanks to @Trogdor

Answer (score 1):

```
disp([fruit{:} ' is ' flavorDb(fruit{:})]);
```

inside the loop should do the trick. `{:}` unpacks the `fruit` ("uncells" it).

Comment: This didn't work for me, although it probably would with `fprintf` instead of `disp`: EDIT, no, containers only support a single key at a time, for loop required

Comment: @Trogdor I didn't say anything about omitting the `for` loop…

Comment: Containers support multiple keys, you just have to use the correct method!

Comment: @glglgl, roger that, I misunderstood your solution